# How is the latest InstallJammer used on a Windows machine?

Tags: installation

I'm using [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) to create installers for my product.  The source and binaries are located on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/installjammer/files/InstallJammer/), but when I downloaded the latest (1.2.15) tar.gz file I found no executables.  I tried running the .tcl files, but without success.

As it happens, I remembered I had an InstallJammer installer (.exe) that I had downloaded months ago for the same version (1.2.15).  Once I ran that, InstallJammer was installed on my Windows machine and I had an "InstallJammer.exe" file in my Program Files directory that launched the GUI.  Afterwards, I searched the web for this InstallJammer installer, but was unable to find it anywhere.

My issue is solved for now, but I'm posting in case anyone else has run into this.  So my official question for the benefit of all is this: how do you get InstallJammer installed on a Windows machine using the sourceforge tar.gz file?  Or, alternatively, where do you find the .exe installer for InstallJammer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've probably read on the InstallJammer website, active development of InstallJammer has been discontinued. The source files are still present, but the Windows installer for version 1.2.15 is no longer available on the Sourceforge site. However there still are some download sites that have the 1.2.15 installer, 
 e.g. [this one](http://download.cnet.com/InstallJammer/3000-2216_4-75451502.htm)

Also on the old [InstallJammer site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/installjammer/files/InstallJammer/snapshots/) there still are 2 snapshot versions with Windows executable. I haven't tried them yet, as I am still using the 1.2.15 version myself.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that cnet link.  As for the InstallJammer site, I tested the snapshot but it looked to be quite different from the 1.2.15 version, and my 1.2.15 workspace did not open properly with the latest snapshot.

Comment: That cnet installer is a freakin' minefield!